# Why does this sscanf modify some data i don't want to be modified?

Tags: c, list, scanf, undefined-behavior, singly-linked-list

I'm reading and saving strings from a formatted file and for some reason I found out `sscanf()` changes `testa_e->ident` contents.

I have put some `printf` around and I found that the problem occurs right after `sscanf()`; I have also checked addresses of `temp2`, `temp5` and `testa_e` by printing them but they are different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define string 30
#define line 100

typedef const char *identifier;

struct nodo_id {
    identifier ident;
    struct nodo_id *next;
};
typedef struct nodo_id nodo_id;

nodo_id *testa_e = NULL;

void addent(const char *id_ent) {
    if (testa_e == NULL) {
        testa_e = malloc(sizeof(nodo_id));
        testa_e->ident = id_ent;
        testa_e->next = NULL;
    } else {
        nodo_id *curs = testa_e;
        while (curs != NULL) {
            curs = curs->next;
        }
        curs = malloc(sizeof(nodo_id));
        curs->ident = id_ent;
        curs->next = NULL;  
    }
}

int main() {
    char temp[line];
    char temp2[string];
    char temp5[string];

    fgets(temp, line, stdin);
    while (strncmp(temp, "end", 3) != 0) {
        if (strncmp(temp, "addent", 6) == 0) {
            if (testa_e != NULL)
                printf("\nbefore sscanf: %s\n", testa_e->ident);
            sscanf(temp, "%s %s", temp5, temp2); 
            if (testa_e != NULL)
                printf("\nafter sscanf: %s\n", testa_e->ident);
            addent(temp2);
        }
        fgets(temp, line, stdin);
    }
}
```

This code here reproduces the exact same problem; after launch write `addent firstword` and  `addent secondword`on terminal and right around `sscanf` it should show you that `testa_e->ident` content has changed, I'd like to know why and how to fix this, because I seriously have no idea...

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but it doesn’t look like your `addent` function can ever add more than one. The loop that traverses the list until `curs` is `NULL` is equivalent to `nodo_id* curs=NULL;`.

Comment: Can you show the full session, including your input and all the output?

Comment: my pc died right now , i'm on phone ill do asap when i get a charge, by "full session" do you mean my complete code?

Comment: I don't know how big your input strings are, but one of `scanf`'s many problems is that it's not convenient to properly prevent buffer overflow.  But you might want to use `sscanf(temp,"%29s %29s",temp5,temp2)`, which should avoid overflowing `temp5` and `temp2`. (Just remember to change the numbers in the `%s` directives if you change the size of the arrays, i.e. if you change `string`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function `addent` this loop

```
        while(curs!=NULL){
            curs=curs->next;
        }
```

iterates until `curs` is equal to `NULL`.

Then you are changing the pointer

```
    curs=malloc(sizeof(nodo_id));
    curs->ident=id_ent;
    curs->next=NULL;
```

The list itself was not changed. You changed only the local variable `curs`.

Change the loop the following way

```
        while ( curs->next != NULL ){
            curs = curs->next;
        }
```

and then

```
    curs->next = malloc( sizeof( nodo_id ) );
    curs->next->ident = id_ent;
    curs->next->next = NULL;
```

The other problem is that you are using pointers to a local array

```
char temp2[string];
//...
addent(temp2);
```

So the last that will be stored in the array will be pointed to by all nodes. You need to allocate dynamically memory for each string that will be stored in the list and assign the address to the data member `ident`. In this case you have to remove the qualifier `const` from its declaration.

Take into account that it is a bad idea to make a function depends on a global variable,

A better definition of the function `addent` can look the following way

```
struct nodo_id{
    char *ident;
    struct nodo_id* next;
};
typedef struct nodo_id nodo_id;

int addent( nodo_id **head, const char *id_ent )
{
    nodo_id *new_nodo_id = malloc( sizeof( nodo_id ) );
    int success = new_nodo_id != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_nodo_id->ident = malloc( strlen( id_ent ) + sizeof( ( char )'\0' ) );

        success = new_nodo_id->ident != NULL;

        if ( ! success )
        {
            free( new_nodo_id );
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy( new_nodo_id->ident, id_ent );
            new_nodo_id->next = NULL;

            while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

            *head = new_nodo_id;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
addent( &testa_e, temo2 );
```

Why in the function there is used the pointer to pointer to the head?

First of all if we want to change the original head we need to pass it by reference. Secondly in the loop

```
while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;
```

again the data member `next` of the last node is pointed to by the pointer. So we are changing not the local variable `curs` as in your implementation of the function but the data member `next` of the last node. So we are changing the list itself.

Pay attention to that defining such a typedef as

```
typedef const char* identifier;
```

is a bad practice.

Comment: @Aconcagua If he will use standard C functions that he needs.

Comment: Depends on what she/he's going to do afterwards with the list, but that's beyond current question. For pure assignment in list nodes, why would I *need* a pointer to non-const?

Comment: The part where you append `new_nodo_id` to the list and change the original `*head` if and only if it had been `NULL`  is really clever but a little bit tricky too. At least I had to think twice. It deserves a comment, I think

Comment: so after i did malloc for `nodo_id` and I stored the string in it, it wasn't actually copied in a new memory zone but `ident` was still pointing at the data of  `temp2` array?

Comment: @wattbatt You are write. The data member ident have the value of the address of the first element of the array temp3. So all nodes will have the same address.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is (besides the one @VladFromMoscow addressed in his answer), that in `addent()` you only store the **pointer** `id_ent` in your struct:

```
curs->ident=id_ent;
```

But that is nothing else but the address of `temp2`, so if you copy something else into `temp2` by calling `sscanf()` you'll see the new value in `testa_e->ident` too.

Change the line form above to

```
curs->ident=strdup(id_ent);
```

to create a copy.
And don't forget to call `free(curs->ident)` when before you are freeing `curs`